# how to automatically add rows in flask html table

Tags: html, flask, flask-table

I'd like to automatically add a row for everytime a new "to-do" item is added.

Here's how it **currently** looks like,

[image]

Here's **how I want it to look like** - under the "CARD_1"

[image]

I have an idea of where I am going wrong with this, from my code we can see that the for loop re-iterates under one row. I'd like to have it add a row automatically whenver my Trello card is updated.

my code:

```html
<table BORDER=1 WIDTH="100%" CELLPADDING="4" CELLSPACING="3">
                <thead>
                    <tr ALIGN="center">
                        <th COLSPAN="4" WIDTH="50%" CELLPADDING="4" CELLSPACING="3">
                            <br>
                            <h1>To-do list</h1>
                            </br>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ALIGN="center ">
                        <td ALIGN="left "><strong>Agenda</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Not Started</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>In Progress</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Complete</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            {%for item in todo_items%}
                            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="id" name="Tick" value="{{item.id}}"></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="id" name="Tick" value="{{item.id}}"></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="id" name="Tick" value="{{item.id}}"></td>
                            {%endfor%}
                        </tr>
                        {% for row in todo_items%}
                        <tr>
                            {%for rwo in cell%}
                            <td>{{cell}}</td>
                            {%endfor%}
                        </tr>
                        {%endfor%}
                    </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the "tr" tag inside the loop:

```
<tbody>
   {%for item in todo_items%}
     <tr>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="id" name="Tick" value="{{item.id}}"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="id" name="Tick" value="{{item.id}}"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="id" name="Tick" value="{{item.id}}"></td>
      </tr>
    {%endfor%}
 </tbody>
```

as it's "tr" that defines new table row.

P.s. what are you trying to achieve with this?

```
{% for row in todo_items%}
  <tr>
    {%for rwo in cell%}
      <td>{{cell}}</td>
    {%endfor%}
  </tr>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, it worked. i don't know what I was doing with that, I am new to flask and just testing stuff out haha. Funny what beginners can do sometimes haha.